# When using ASP.NET how do you impersonate Windows Credentials?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created asp.net (vb.net) website which uses IWA. Works perfectly no issues.

However now i have users who are not necessarily part of my company domain but login to my network to access public information.

I have created a Public Account on my AD. What I would like to do is, when the external users log-in, be able to pass the Public Account credentials so they can have access to the public information.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporary impersonate user:

in c# but you can easy translate it to vb

```
    if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
    {
       if (LogonUser("TempUser", Environment.MachineName, 
                  "password", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                  LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
       {
          if (DuplicateToken(token, SecurityImpersonation, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
          {
            m_ImpersonatedUser = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
            m_ImpersonationContext = m_ImpersonatedUser.Impersonate();                                
            try
            {
                // impersonated code here       
            }        
            catch { throw; }
            finally
            {
              m_ImpersonationContext.Undo();
            }
          }
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set up the credentials using the identity impersonation setting in the web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <identity impersonate="true" userName="foo" password="bar"/>
</system.web>
```

You should also encrypt the web.config so that the password is not stored in plaintext. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b.aspx

Another option is to give your users the ability impersonate as your service account in code. Note, this code in C#, but I wrote it for doing on the fly Windows impersonation. It can be compiled as a DLL and referenced in VB.NET:

```
/// <summary>
/// Facilitates impersonation of a Windows User.
/// </summary>
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public class Impersonation : IDisposable
{
    public string Environment { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string DomainName { get; set; }

    public enum LogonType
    {
        Interactive = 2,
        Network = 3,
        Batch = 4,
        Service = 5,
        Unlock = 7,
        NetworkClearText = 8,
        NewCredentials = 9
    }

    public enum LogonProvider
    {
        Default = 0,
        WinNT35 = 1,
        WinNT40 = 2,
        WinNT50 = 3
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Windows Token.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly SafeTokenHandle _handle;

    /// <summary>
    /// The impersonated User.
    /// </summary>
    private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser;

    public Impersonation()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Impersonation class. Provides domain, user name, and password for impersonation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domainName">Domain name of the impersonated user.</param>
    /// <param name="userName">Name of the impersonated user.</param>
    /// <param name="password">Password of the impersonated user.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Uses the unmanaged LogonUser function to get the user token for
    /// the specified user, domain, and password.
    /// </remarks>
    public Impersonation(AccountCredentials credentials)
    {            
        string[] splitName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\');
        string name = (splitName.Length > 0) ? splitName[0] : null;

        LogonType logonType = LogonType.Interactive;
        LogonProvider logonProvider = LogonProvider.Default;

        if (name != credentials.Domain)
        {
            logonType = LogonType.NewCredentials;
            logonProvider = LogonProvider.WinNT50;
        }

        // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
        bool returnValue = LogonUser(
                            credentials.UserName,
                            credentials.Domain,
                            credentials.Password,
                            (int)logonType,
                            (int)logonProvider,
                            out this._handle);

        if (!returnValue)
        {
            // Something went wrong.
            int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
        }

        this.impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(this._handle.DangerousGetHandle());    
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the Impersonation class. Provide domain, user name, and password for impersonation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domainName">Domain name of the impersonated user.</param>
    /// <param name="userName">Name of the impersonated user.</param>
    /// <param name="password">Password of the impersonated user.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Uses the unmanaged LogonUser function to get the user token for
    /// the specified user, domain, and password.
    /// </remarks>
    public Impersonation(string domainName, string userName, string password)
    {
        string[] splitName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\');
        string name = (splitName.Length > 0) ? splitName[0] : null;

        LogonType logonType = LogonType.Interactive;
        LogonProvider logonProvider = LogonProvider.Default;

        if (name != domainName)
        {
            logonType = LogonType.NewCredentials;
            logonProvider = LogonProvider.WinNT50;
        }

        // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
        bool returnValue = LogonUser(
                            userName,
                            domainName,
                            password,
                            (int)logonType,
                            (int)logonProvider,
                            out this._handle);

        if (!returnValue)
        {
                // Something went wrong.
            int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
        }

        this.impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(this._handle.DangerousGetHandle());
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(
            string lpszUsername,
            string lpszDomain,
            string lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.impersonatedUser.Dispose();
        this._handle.Dispose();
    }

    private static string[] GetAccountInfo(string accountInfo)
    {
        return accountInfo.Split(' ');
    }
}

public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private SafeTokenHandle()
        : base(true) { }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}

public class AccountCredentials
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}
```

Then you would do your impersonated actions in a using block:

```
using(new Impersonation(new AccountCredentials("user", "password", "domain"))
{
    // do impersonated actions
}
```

You need to have these using directives in your class:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Security;
using System.Configuration;
```

Comment: This would make all his users assume this windows credential which is not what he needs. He is looking into some kind of mixed mode authentication where users inside the network use their credentials, but users outside should use all the same account.

Comment: I've added code for doing on the fly impersonation. It was written in C#, but could be referenced as a DLL in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the informative answers... Sorry for getting back so late...So what i have done now is this ....

Imports System.Web.Security

Imports System.Security.Principal

Imports System.Security.Permissions

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Imports System.Environment

Public Class Redirect
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE As Integer = 2
Dim LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT As Integer = 0

Dim impersonationContext As WindowsImpersonationContext

Declare Function LogonUserA Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal lpszUsername As String, _
                        ByVal lpszDomain As String, _
                        ByVal lpszPassword As String, _
                        ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, _
                        ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, _
                        ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Integer

Declare Auto Function DuplicateToken Lib "advapi32.dll" ( _
                        ByVal ExistingTokenHandle As IntPtr, _
                        ByVal ImpersonationLevel As Integer, _
                        ByRef DuplicateTokenHandle As IntPtr) As Integer

Declare Auto Function RevertToSelf Lib "advapi32.dll" () As Long
Declare Auto Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Long

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim redirstr As Integer
    redirstr = Request.QueryString("id")
    If impersonateValidUser("*username*", "*Domain*", "*Password*") Then
        'Insert your code that runs under the security context of a specific user here.

        Try
            'Integrated Windows Authentication Site
            Response.Redirect("http://<<servername>>/<app>/<<file>")

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        undoImpersonation()
    Else
        'Your impersonation failed. Therefore, include a fail-safe mechanism here.
    'Not Integrated Windows Authentication Site
        Response.Redirect("http://<<servername>>:81/<app>/<<file>?user=<<username>>&pass=<<password>>)
    End If

End Sub

Private Function impersonateValidUser(ByVal userName As String, _
ByVal domain As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean

    Dim tempWindowsIdentity As WindowsIdentity
    Dim token As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim tokenDuplicate As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    impersonateValidUser = False

    If RevertToSelf() Then
        If LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                     LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, token) <> 0 Then
            If DuplicateToken(token, 2, tokenDuplicate) <> 0 Then
                tempWindowsIdentity = New WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate)
                impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate()
                If Not impersonationContext Is Nothing Then
                    impersonateValidUser = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If Not tokenDuplicate.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate)
    End If
    If Not token.Equals(IntPtr.Zero) Then
        CloseHandle(token)
    End If
End Function

Private Sub undoImpersonation()
    impersonationContext.Undo()
End Sub
```

End Class

So in this case ideally it should be passing the actions to the IWA site if my authentication passes. Which it does, however once i enter the IWA site it takes my windows credentials and not the one that i am trying to impersonate. How do i achieve this... where could go to the site using my impersonated windows user credentials ?